Can I delete Reserved Partitions Windows created on my non-OS storage drives?
Disk 0 has 3 x OS on partitions: 10 pro, 11 pro & 10 pro 2, as well as its own Windows created Reserved Partition (16 MB).
Disks 1 to 7 are non-OS data storage drives. On Disk 1 to 7 I manually created a 16 or 17 MB unallocated space at disk start followed by the storage partition taking up the rest of each disk.
I don't know why but on 4 of the data storage drives Windows has allocated the 16 or 17 MB spaces and set them as Reserved Partitions. They are showing as file system *Other and full.
Can I wipe these 4 Reserved Partitions on the storage disks and restore them back to unallocated, or leave them?
Here is a screenshot of my disk layout showing what I have described:


Sure you can delete them, but to what end?

They are probably the partitions necessary for the GPT structure. As long as you use this partition structure, these partitions are necessary even if they are empty. Note that they have a special partition type. They should not be of the NTFS type. See the Wikipedia entry related to this matter

They are not necessary. Not for GPT and also not for Windows.

As stated by Daniel B, in this instance the system allocated reserved partitions on the non-OS storage disks (NOT the reserved partition on the OS disk) could safely be deleted without any effect upon the disks function. Thank you Daniel B.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
